# Mysql Really get rows from result?

Tags: mysql

Good day.

For page navigation useally need use two query:
1) `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table");`

-- query which get all count rows for make links on previous and next pages, example <- 2 3 **4** 5 6 ->)

2) `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 20, $num"); // where $num - count rows for page`

Tell me please really use only one query to database for make links on previous and next pages ( <- 2 3 **4** 5 6 -> ) and output rows from page (sql with limit) ?

*p.s.: i know that can use two query and `SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 20` - it not answer.*

Comment: If you only want 20 rows why can't you use LIMIT? You need to explain yourself better.

Comment: @JohnConde becouse i not want use two query for paginator (page navigation)

Comment: I don't understand what you want.. you want 20 rows even if you got 40? Just loop 20 times instead 40, it's not that hard.

Comment: And what is wrong with `$query = "SELECT * FROM table"; $query .= ' LIMIT 20"`?

Comment: PHP page for mysql_query(): Warning This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0,

Comment: Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement...

Comment: @N.B. i update question, see again please

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv i update question, see again please

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how many rows *would* have been returned from a query while still using LIMIT you can use [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, * FROM Table");
$count_result = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows);
$total_rows = $rows['found_rows'];
```

This is still two queries (which is inevitable) but is lighter on the DB as it doesn't actually have to run your main query twice.

Comment: @learner - this is your answer. Just use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with LIMIT clause and read carefully what John wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Many database APIs don't actually grab all the rows of the result set until you access them.

For example, using Python's built-in sqlite:

```
q = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM somehwere")

row1 = q.fetchone()
row2 = q.fetchone()
```

Of course the library is free to prefetch unknown number of rows to improve performance.